# Removing leaflet markers in Angular not working

Tags: angular, leaflet

I am currently working on an OpenSteetMap project using Leaflet and Angular. 
I am trying to remove certain markers based on a custom property. Unfortunately, the code is not working as expected:

```
 map.eachLayer(layer => {
  if (!(layer instanceof L.TileLayer) && layer.options.isNewMarker) {
    console.warn('Removed layer');
    map.removeLayer(layer);
  }
});
```

Although the function map.removeLayer() is called, the marker is not removed from the map.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is it going wrong? Does the console statement log? if you debug into the method, where does the behavior deviate from the expected?

Comment: After reviewing the code once again, I figured out that i was adding two markers at the same time and only one of them had the custom property set. Sorry for the trouble!

Answer (score 0):

I was accidentally adding two markers at the same time, one without having the custom property set!